How to load all JSON files for a given day in a hive partitioned from Google Cloud Storage Bucket into a polars dataframe?
I have a Google Cloud Storage project with a bucket.
In this bucket the files are partitioned via Hive partition, e.g.:
gs://my_bucket/vendor/updates/year=2024/month=08/day=01/company_a.json
gs://my_bucket/vendor/updates/year=2024/month=08/day=01/company_b.json
gs://my_bucket/vendor/updates/year=2024/month=08/day=01/company_c.json

gs://my_bucket/vendor/updates/year=2024/month=08/day=02/company_a.json
gs://my_bucket/vendor/updates/year=2024/month=08/day=02/company_b.json

According to the documentation (https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/io/cloud-storage/) one can load all parquet, csv or ipc file from a given hive partition via:
import polars as pl
source = "s3://bucket/*.parquet"
df = pl.read_parquet(source)

Since every day may contain many files I need a performant way to load every JSON file for a given year, year/month or year/month/day into a dataframe.
Trying the same as above
import polars as pl
source = "gs://my_bucket/vendor/updates/year=2024/month=08/day=01/*.json"
df = pl.read_json(source)

results in the following error message:

OSError: Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch. (os error 123)

What is the best way to solve this?
